# PHP Get array of a property from array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an API that sends me the data in the format

```
[{"part_no":"AAA"},{"part_no":"BBB"},{"part_no":"CCC"},......{"part_no":"ZZZ"}]
```

I want to create an array like `["AAA", "BBB", ...., "ZZZ"]` from the above array.

I know it's possible by iterating the array item by item, and appending it to a new array, but thought that there might be a better (and hopefully faster) approach.

Like `C#` has`Linq` that does this all in a one-liner, JS has `map`, it is possible to do a similar thing in PHP ?

Comment: `$out = array_map(fn($item) => $item['part_no'], $in);` or, if it's a simple associative array: `$out = array_column($in, 'part_no');`

Comment: Prior to PHP7.4: `$out = array_map(function ($part) { return $part['part_no']; }, json_decode($data, true));`

Comment: _and hopefully faster_ Of course there are one liners in PHP, but it is _not faster than looping_.

Comment: @Nick I'm using `7.2`, and your code returns `null`

Comment: Is your JSON variable called `$data`?

Comment: @Nick no i changed it to my variable name lol

Comment: @Nick, got it working.. thanks ! it shouldn't have `json_decode` in the end. Just passing the array solved it

Comment: @mrid ah cool, was just about to post this link https://3v4l.org/PXQ1P

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$json = '[{"part_no":"AAA"},{"part_no":"BBB"},{"part_no":"CCC"},{"part_no":"ZZZ"}]';
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$result = array_column($data, 'part_no');
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 'AAA',
    1 => 'BBB',
    2 => 'CCC',
    3 => 'ZZZ',
  )
```